# Spock - data table for expected output

Tags: groovy, spock, data-driven-tests

Reading http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html, it seems that data tables are a convenient, readable way to structure test inputs. I'd like to structure my test output in a similar way.

I have a method under test which returns an `Iterable<Entry<String, String>>`. I have the following Spock test case, but something tells me there is a way I can make Spock do more of this for me. This is essentially just Java code, so I suspect there is a groovier way. Can this be simplified?

```
def "iterate" () {
    given:
    Iterator expected =
    ['one'    : 'a',
     'two'    : 'b',
     'three'  : 'c',
     'four'   : 'd',
     'five'   : 'e',
     'six'    : 'f'].entrySet().iterator()

    when:
    Iterable<Entry<String, String>> actual = testClass.method()

    then:
    for (def entry : actual) {
        assert entry == expected.next()
    }
}
```

Comment: Spock's data driven testing won't help here.

Comment: If you found my answer useful please accept and upvote it.

Comment: @Opal, sorry, it wasn't useful, as per my comment on the answer. I upvoted Peter's comment, which I think is the authoritative answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The result of this test is unpredictable since iteration order over set is not defined (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752753/java-set-retain-order)) and when comparing elements of two sets in the way in the code it will almost fail for sure.

Here's how it should look:

```
def "iterate" () {
    given:
    Iterator expected =
    ['one'    : 'a',
     'two'    : 'b',
     'three'  : 'c',
     'four'   : 'd',
     'five'   : 'e',
     'six'    : 'f'].entrySet()

    when:
    Iterable<Entry<String, String>> actual = testClass.method()

    then:
    expected == actual as Set
}
```

Comment: Groovy by default uses LinkedHashMap (and LinkedHashSet) so the keys are ordered. My original code works; I only suspected there was a way that I could avoid explicitly calling the iterator. Coercing the Iterable is a good idea, but unfortunately the equality comparison fails: the contents are equal but the underlying types are still different.