# Set interface and natural ordering [nonsensical interview test]

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

By a chance it happened to me twice that I got the same Java question during a job interview Java test. For me it seems like a nonsense. It goes something like this:

> Which of this collections would you use if you needed a collection with no
>   duplicates and with natural ordering?
>
> 1. java.util.List
> 2. java.util.Map
> 3. java.util.Set
> 4. java.util.Collection

The closest answer would be `Set`. But as far as I know these interfaces, with exception of `List` do not define any ordering in their contract but it is the matter of the implementing classes to have or not to have defined ordering.

Was I right in pointing out in the test that the question is wrong?

Comment: Definitely. The only correct answer is 'none of the above', or `java.util.SortedSet.`

Comment: @MaxZoom Come off it. He knows that. Not what he's asking. Read the question.

Comment: @EJP I added my point of view below.

Comment: The question is not wrong.  Clearly Map is inappropriate.  Since List and Set both extend Collection the answer must be Collection.  The class you willbprobaby end up using SortedSet implements both Set and Collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're correct that none of the answers given matches the requirements. A correct answer might have been `SortedSet` or its subinterface `NavigableSet`.

Answer (score 4):

The first major clue is "no duplicates." A mathematical set contains only unique items, which means no duplicates, so you are correct here.

In terms of ordering, perhaps the interviewer was looking for you to expand upon your answer. Just as a "Set" extends a "Collection" (in Java), there are more specific types of "Sets" possible in Java. See: [HashSet, TreeSet, LinkedHashSet.](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/hashset-vs-treeset-vs-linkedhashset/) For example, TreeSet is inherited from [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) interface.

However, it is most definitely true that a Java set does not [provide any ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752753/java-set-retain-order). Frankly, I think this is a poorly worded question and you were right to point out the lack in precision.

Answer (score 2):

A [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) with natural ordering is a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) (which extends `Set` so it is-a `Set`), and a concrete implementation of that interface is [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (which implements `SortedSet` so it is-a `Set`).

Comment: @MaxZoom In the context of a job interview, on a multiple choice exam I would mark "3. `java.util.Set`" (and if given the opportunity, I would explain my reasoning as set forth in my answer here).

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer for that test is **`Set`** Let's remember that it's asking for an interface that could provide that; given the **right implementation**, the `Set` interface could provide it.

- The `Map` interface doesn't make any guarantees around what order
  things are stored, as that's implementation specific. However, if you
  use the right implementation (that is, `[TreeMap][1]` as spelled out 
  by the    docs), then you're guaranteed a natural ordering and no
  duplicate    entries.   However, there's no requirement about
  key-value pairs.
- The `Set` interface also doesn't make any guarantees around what order 
  things are stored in, as that's implementation specific.    But, like
  `TreeMap`, `[TreeSet][2]` is a set that can be used to store    things in a
  natural order with no duplicates.   Here's how it'd look.
  `Set<String> values = new TreeSet<>();`
- The List interface will    definitely allow duplicates, which
  instantly rules it out.
- The Collection interface doesn't have anything directly implementing 
  it, but it is the patriarch of the entire collections    hierarchy.
  So,    in theory, code like this is legal:

  `Collection<String> values = new TreeSet<>();`

  ...but you'd lose    information about what
  kind of collection it actually was, so I'd       discourage its
  usage.